# How to demonize face in a video

Tags: video, software-rec, video-editing

What program can I use to turn a human face into a devil or demon face in a video easily?

There are some examples on Youtube (<sup>[1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D48BYHnIREM)</sup><sup>,</sup><sup>[2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dC7h3sj5kto)</sup><sup>,</sup><sup>[3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIGxKY5y6Mg)</sup>). Apparently, they have used a user-friendly and easy-to-use software for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definitely wasn't user-friendly or easy-to-use software, or at least not a one-click solution.

The third video you posted is "the original" and I know I've seen it before. Probably some viral marketing scheme. The second one is a "ripoff", if you can say that, and my best guess is that you can use **After Effects** for it, [like this guy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNK1OQ0-Xhc).

Turns out, there are a [couple of tutorials](http://www.5min.com/Video/How-to-Add-Demon-Face-Warp-in-After-Effects-21791195) on the very same subject, do a [Google search](http://www.google.at/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=after+effects+distort+face#hl=en&pq=after%20effects%20distort%20face&xhr=t&q=after+effects+face+warp&cp=20&pf=p&sclient=psy&safe=off&source=hp&aq=0v&aqi=&aql=&oq=after+effects+face+w&pbx=1&fp=4794931d559102b1) for it.

Comment: Nice tutorial. +1